# Has the "Hellblazer" Constantine ever met Lucifer?

Tags: dc, vertigo-comics, constantine-2005, constantine, hellblazer

In the 2005 "Constantine" movie the main character in the climax of the has a small tête–à–tête with the Devil- aka [Lucifer Morningstar](http://hellblazer.wikia.com/wiki/Lucifer_Morningstar).

[image: Illustration of Lucifer whispering to Constantie "You will live John Constantine, so you have the chance to prove that your soul truly belongs in Hell]

But in the Vertigo comic book universe, Lucifer has quit the job:

> He became tired of the various stereotypes and prejudices that mortals held of him, such as the idea that he purchased and traded for souls, which were largely untrue, and that he forced mortals to commit evil acts. He had become tired of his reign over Hell, and felt it an unfair punishment that he should have to rule there forever simply because he once rebelled.

His job has been taken by the [First of the Fallen](http://hellblazer.wikia.com/wiki/The_First_of_the_Fallen), being much older that old Luc, who rules together with the Second and Third of the Fallen (until he realized that he is much more powerful than them) and he, not Morningstar is usually the main opponent of John Constantine.

[image: Constantine giving the finger to the Fallen]

So has Constantine ever met the original Devil?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Constantine):

> Constantine also makes a small cameo in Vertigo's *Lucifer*. In issue No. 5 he is seen drinking at Lucifer Morningstar's bar Lux, among guests that seek an audience with Lucifer about the gateway to the void outside of creation. According to himself he's not there to propose a trade with Lucifer, only to take "a quick look at the field". Lucifer Morningstar makes a return cameo in *Hellblazer* No. 192. Lucifer writer Mike Carey wrote Hellblazer between issues 175–215.

Comment: Part of the New 52, I...Vampire #19, I believe he does. (At least the wiki lends itself to that).

Comment: The lucifer comics is a spinoff of Sandman. In the first Sandman stories, where Lucifer Morningstar eventually resigns from hell, we get references to Lucifer previously being part of a triumvirate. This triumvirate we met in an earlier Hellblazer story arch, where comics-Constantine plays the three up against each other. Constantine and the 3 met in a room on earth.  So without room for confusion of appearances or naming, they did indeed meet.

Comment: @Abulafia the question is did they meet in person. Constantine has been in Hell (many times) and in Lux (but when Lucifer was in another word). There are panels with Lucifer in "Hellblazer" comic (but again, Luc is somewhere else) and they both are at wake in Sandman. But I'm asking have they met in person, face to face.

Comment: @Yasskier: Sorry, should have done my googling here. I believed Ennis' "First of the fallen" and Gaiman's "Lucifer Morningstar" were supposed to be the same character, but Ennis decided they were not. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_of_the_Fallen

Answer (score 1):

In the comics, I cannot be sure. I haven't read all of the Constantine/Hellblazer or Sandman comics. However, I do know that besides the aforementioned film, Lucifer Morningstar and John Constantine met in the **Arrowverse's "Crisis on Infinite Earths" crossover, specifically part 3**. In it, after

> the death and resurrection of Oliver Queen,

John Constantine, John Diggle, and Mia Queen travel to Earth-666 (get it?) in order to meet Lucifer. John and Lucifer appear to have had a history, although Lucifer intentionally pronounces Constantine incorrectly. Morningstar provides the trio with a card that gives them access to Purgatory in order to retrieve

> Oliver's soul.

[Lucifer Morningstar meets Constantine|Crisis on Infinite Earths Hour two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbiRAcbCiGE)

Comment: Ooo,  that is an interesting modern crossover, however, I had the original comic in mind. I guess I should make that clearer... but still it is a good answer :)